# Check box counter function applied to todo items in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode, is there a function to perform the [x/y] counter function on a list of "todo" items, similar to that feature which exists for checkbox?  (That is, to automatically count the number of items that are in a non-done state.)

Comment: It's similar to checkboxes: https://orgmode.org/manual/Breaking-down-tasks.html

Comment: Pretty simple.  Thanks for not saying RTFM!

Answer (score 1):

I think comments below your question already provide the answer for your question. But also check [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Breaking-Down-Tasks.html), that guide you how you can make this counter recursive across the hierarchy of nested to-dos.